# JUnit Test does not start Selenium WebDriver

Tags: firefox, junit, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i have a JUnit test where my WebDriver does not start out of a sudden.
I have Firefox version 14.0.1 and I'm using Selenium 2.25.0

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
//Test running here
```

The debug does not get over creating the firefox driver instance. I have no clue, why it doesn't work anymore since I was able to start the same test a week ago.

Comment: Do you mean the driver actually gets launched or it fails at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Since your debugger does not get to the creation of the driver, it sounds like your setUp() method is not even executing.  So if I am reading this right, the first problem to solve is getting your driver-creation code to execute, rather than with figuring out what's wrong with the code (which looks ok at first glance).

Try running this test in isolation from other tests in an environment where you can confirm that execution of a single JUnit test works properly.

Comment: Already solved it by myself, Eclipse did not update references, so I had to restart the whole scenario.
Thanks anyway